# Планировщик заданий. Немедленно запускать задачу

Tags: windows, планировщик-задач

В параметрах задачи я поставил галочку около параметра "Немедленно запускать задачу, если пропущен плановый запуск". Я поискал в интернете и нашел, что задача выполняется в данном случае не сразу, а через некоторое время, по умолчанию - 10 минут. Как и где менять это значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [схеме по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-schema) для Планировщика единственное значение, равное 10 минутам, это - `IdleDuration`, но этот параметр устанавливает время простоя системы по умолчанию, после которого компьютер запускает задачу, где это указано в качестве триггера.
Можно, конечно, попробовать изменить этот параметр (либо создать и зарегистрировать свою схему с измененным параметром), но я сомневаюсь, что это подействует.
Судя по всему, 10 минут либо зашито в сам Планировщик со времён Vista, либо (маловероятно) где-то в глубинах реестра в виде недокументированной фичи :)